# How to make parent view bind command with child view-model method

Tags: winforms, mvvm, devexpress

I have a simpleButton in parent view and I want to bind this button with a method in child view-model.

```
_fluentApi.BindCommand(simpleButton , x => x.SaveMessage());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DevExpress MVVM [Fluent API](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/117019/Build-an-Application/WinForms-MVVM/Concepts/Fluent-API-Support) supports binding to nested properties/commands:

```
// ViewModel
public class ParentViewModel {
    public ParentViewModel() {
        Child = ChildViewModel.Create();
    }
    public virtual ChildViewModel Child { 
        get;
        protected set;
    }
}
public class ChildViewModel{
    public static ChildViewModel Create() {
        return DevExpress.Mvvm.POCO.ViewModelSource.Create<ChildViewModel>();
    }
    public void Save(){
        // ...
    }
}

// View
var fluentApi = mvvmContext.OfType<ParentViewModel>()
fluentApi.BindCommand(simpleButton , x => x.Child.Save());
```

Comment: but when make a child class inherit from parent class it's return an error.

Comment: ex: public class ChildViewModel : ParentViewModel

Comment: Because of you introduce recursive dependency in this case - "to create Child you should create Child." OMG))

Comment: It's working to call child view-model method in parent view but the model object that was created in child view-model is  null even child view is already created.

Comment: why It's cannot synchronize with each other. @DmitryG

Comment: I have already described the reason. The example I have provided above works as it should without any errors. In the modified example, there is no problem with ChildViewModel method call because of it **static call** and do not depend on inheritance. Refer to the programming language reference for details. To ensure the recursion you can use the **step-by-step debugging**. If something is still unclear you are free to create a separate question and provide the exact code snippet which raises the issue.